# How binary file can be portable in C programming?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, portability

After reading some C programming books, I would like to understand something about portability. C code is portable, but must be recompiled on each machine, so that the compiler can generate the right assembler and binary code for the processor.

Yet, when I download games (portable games) that contain some files, the .exe files work without needing to be recompiled on my machine.

So, how can be there a portable .exe?

Comment: The web site from which you download the game knows the kind of operating system you use.  So you'll of course get an EXE that works on your machine.

Comment: @karim try to read some articles Googled for "portable executable file format", e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx It should give you the answers. You question does not fit the Stack Overflow question format (see help)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All Windows machines use the same two architectures (x64 or x86).

That means that if you want to run on a *different* architecture, such as Linux, you need to recompile.

Comment: Yes, except Windows can run on ARM now, and the reason things have to be recompiled more often on Linux is that every single distribution is just different enough to break binary compatibility.

Comment: but i read that each processor has it **own** assembler instruction, so how a computer using windows with the intel processor can execute code compiled in an amd processor

Comment: x64 and x86 are CPU architectures; Linux runs on both. Nevertheless, Windows executables won't run directly on Linux (unless you use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) or something similar).

Comment: @karim: Intel and AMD processors both have the same `x86` instruction set (and so the same assembly can execute on each). It's just their hardware implementations that differ.

Comment: AMD is a company, not a CPU architecture. Intel and AMD both make x86 CPUs, which are compatible. Intel and AMD also both make x86-64 CPUs, which are also able to run x86 code.

Comment: @Cameron: Yes, and you do need to recompile to run on ARM.  (except that Windows on ARM won't let you run classical EXEs anyway)